# Django multi host url configuration per app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I searched around here on SO for how I would setup different domains for apps within a single django project. e.g.: news.io, jobs.io, etc for a news, job, etc app within the main project.

The app will also have authentication where the user will need to remain signed in across the domains if this matters. e.g. - billing platforms, etc.

The recommendation was to use a MultiHostMiddleware found [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultiHostMiddleware) which is obviously outdated.

Similarly, the other recommendation was to use [django-multihost](https://github.com/jaddison/django-multihost) which is also *really* old.

I'm on Django 1.11 and Python 3.6. Is there anything more recent or better yet how would I roll my own?

Comment: Why is [`sites`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/) not enough?

Comment: @kichik I find the documentation a little vague for my use case and have no idea where I would even start much less how to share the authentication etc across the domains using sites.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting into this myself, and from what I can tell [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) seems to be the best option.

Comment: From what I saw glancing at the docs this appears to be for subdomains? Not differing domains.

Comment: I *think* you can do what you want with DNS. e.g. Point domain1.com to domain1.myapp.com.

Comment: Yes that would work but not a viable solution. Subdomains aren't an option.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not?